# Flutter: Sizing two Text children in a Row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I broke my brain trying to find a solution. I have a row constrained by screen width and unconstrained by height. Here is an example, constrained by Container for simplicity:

```dart
Container(
  color: Colors.blue[100],
  width: 300,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    children: [
      Container(width: 24, height: 24, color: Colors.red),
      Flexible(
        fit: FlexFit.tight,
        child: Text('$name', overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)
      ),
      Flexible(
        fit: FlexFit.tight,
        child: Text('$value', overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, maxLines: 10, softWrap: true, textAlign: TextAlign.right)
      )
    ]
  )
)
```

I need to size *name* and *value* according to this requirements:

- Consider red square as icon with constant size
- *name* is always 1 line with ellipsis if overflowed
- *value* can be up to 10 lines with ellipsis if overflowed
- In most cases *value* is pretty short, so *name* should take all available space
- When *value* is long, it should take up to 10 lines in height and all available space in width leaving only 50 pixels for *name*. And 24 for icon of course. So *name* should have min width of 50px.

I have no idea how to achieve this. Please help.

P.S. I wrote a big Flutter project, solved huge amount of tricky tasks and Widget puzzles but this thing is something unbelievable.